# IIS 7.5 hosted web service soap calls return http response

Tags: sql, web-services, soap, iis-7.5

I have a .NET, WCF web service (created in PowerBuilder 12.5.1) hosted on an IIS 7.5 server which has a method call that takes an integer, and then makes a call to a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Using Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 I can see that my client makes an HTTP request to the IIS server, which sometimes sends an HTTP 100 response and sometimes doesn't (has never been an issue, and in this case I don't care), then the client makes a SOAP request to the server that has the details for the service call. However, the IIS server just sends back an HTTP 200 response, instead of making the SQL call like its supposed to. There is no indication that the service is even attempting to make a connection to the SQL database. Both the IIS site and application that the service is hosted on are using the PBDotnet4AppPool, which is using integrated managed pipeline mode and the NetworkService Identity. The application has a connection string that can be used to connect to the SQL database with a user id that has read access to all the tables on the database.

How can I fix this so that the service makes the SQL call and returns the proper response? Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm new at this, please be patient and let me know if there is some other information I should have included.

Comment: Why did you expect to to be able to see the traffic to the SQL Server? It won't be HTTP.

Comment: It is supposed to be in the TDS protocol, and it should happen before the service sends a response back to the client. Also the service response should be SOAP, not HTTP.

Comment: Is TDS based on HTTP? SOAP, OTOH, does run over HTTP.

Comment: Not from what I can tell. Either way the network monitor uniquely identifies the different protocols, so that's not an issue. When I host the service as a Console ("Self-Hosted") Application it works fine. On the network monitor I can see the client makes an HTTP request, the service sends an HTTP response, the client makes a SOAP request, the service makes the SQL call (on the network monitor I can see the TDS data transfers), then the service sends a SOAP response to the client containing the data from the SQL call.

Comment: I'm sorry, from your question I gathered that you were not seeing the SQL traffic at all. What is it that you're not seeing?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify a moment. I have 2 copies of my service, one hosted on the ISS 7.5 server and one hosted on my machine as a console application (so I can use a debugger on it). The console application one runs fine and the network monitor shows that the communication between the client, service, and SQL server is how it should be. The service hosted on ISS is not working. After it receives the SOAP request from the client it immediately send the HTTP 200 response without communicating with the SQL server at all. Code-wise the 2 services are identical, except for the host-site URL.

Comment: Suggestions: I presume you mean that the IIS case returns 200, but the wrong response? In that case, try running the console app on the IIS server, monitoring the network traffic. If it fails, you'll know something; if it succeeds but you can't see the TDS traffic, then you'll know something else.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and ran the console app on the IIS server. This time when I ran the client it sent its SOAP request and once again the service never made any communication with the SQL server. However instead of sending an HTTP response it send a SOAP response that was just empty.

Comment: I think you should change your console application to have it do some logging. In particular, make it tell you _explicitly_ whether or not the SQL operations are succeeding. Don't depend on looking at the network traffic to determine success or failure.

Comment: I turned my logging functionality back on in my console service and when I tried to run it on my local machine to test the logging I got the "Transaction not connected" error when I try to connect to the database.

Comment: I don't know what sort of logging you must have to get an error like that; try just logging whether the SQL query succeeded.

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with Powerbuilder and the IIS server than with the IIS server and the SQL server. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the whole thing was a .dll file issue with Powerbuilder. When a powerbuilder web service can't find .dll files it needs it tends to just silently crash and not tell you why. To solve this problem I copied the contents of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder" from my development computer (running Windows 7) to the same folder on the IIS server. After I did this both the console "self-hosted" application service on the IIS server and the IIS hosted service worked fine.

Comment: Where on the IIS server did you copy those files to?

Comment: Its the same file path on both the server and my computer. I edited the answer to include this